# 自分のサーバー上に保存したファイルが勝手に CDN で使用されたら？

Tags: javascript

ふと疑問に思ったのですが、

自分が所有するレンタルサーバーに Javascript のファイルを置いていて、
src="" で自分のサイトで読み込んだ場合に、そのディレクトリがわかると思いますが、
これを誰かが CDN で使用された場合に、自分のサーバーに負荷はかかるのでしょうか。

また、これをセキュリティの観点から防ぐにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Comment: この質問の「セキュリティの観点」で守りたい対象は何ですか？

Comment: @hiro 「そのディレクトリがわかる」というのはどのディレクトリのことでしょうか？

Comment: http://example.com というサイトで <script src="/xxx/sample.js"> となっていれば、これが example.com/xxx/sample.js というパスであることがわかると思うのですが、これを別の人間が大量に使用した場合に、example.com を管理している自分のサーバーに負荷がかかるのか、という質問です。また、かかる場合は、どのようにしたら CDN で使用されることを防げるのか、が追質問になります。

Comment: 「CDNで使用」というのはどういうことでしょうか？自分のレンサバのソースを誰かがCDNに登録して、更新があるたびに誰かがCDNを更新して、CDN側で配信されるということでしょうか？

Comment: CDN という言葉を誤用しているのでしたら、質問の意図は上記の sample.js を誰かが自身のウェブサイトで <script src="http://example.com/xxx/sample.js"> と使用し、そこに大量のアクセスがあったそれを保存しているサーバーに負荷がかかるのかかからないのかが最初の質問になります。@keitaro_so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

答えとしては、
負荷がかかります。これはWebを公開している以上発生してしまう問題です。

いくつか制約（ライセンスや技術的な制限）をかけて防ぐことはできるかもしれないですが、
あまり見かけません。
殆どの場合そのコストと見合うだけのリスクがないというのが実態なのではないかなと思います。

たとえば、
汎用的で有用なライブラリとして利用できるJavascriptであるならば、一般的にはjQueryやその他のライブラリのようにCDNを用意して公開します。
しかし、殆どのJavascriptは1サイトの特定の機能や仕様に基づいたそのサイト向けのJavascriptなので
流用できるものではないでしょう。

また
仮に有用なライブラリであり、外部リンクを利用して自分のサイトに埋め込んだとします。
しかし、参照先の外部サイトがなくなったり、JSのディレクトリが変わったり、もしくは仕様の変更があった場合に、不具合が発生してしまうことになります。
そうなるのであれば、コピペして自分のサイトのJavascriptとして利用することになるでしょう。

上記のことを考えるとあまり考えるべきリスクではないかなという判断できると思いますがいかがでしょうか？

P.S.
CDNはコンテンツを最適に配信できるサービスのことを指し、
外部ドメインのコンテンツを利用することを指す言葉では有りません。
Javascriptのライブラリ界隈では快適に外部ドメインでソースを利用するために、CDNを利用しています。

Answer (score 1):

一例として、WebサーバがApacheであれば以下の様に `.htaccess`を使って別ドメインからのいわゆる
"直リンク" を禁止する方法があるようです。

**参考:**
[.htaccess で別ドメインから画像やスクリプトファイルへの直リンク禁止する方法](https://webllica.com/deny-requests-from-another-domains-by-htaccess/)

URLの部分にアクセスを許可する(自分自身の)ドメインを指定。上記のサイトには指定した拡張子のファイルのみに制限をかける方法なども紹介されています。

> ```
> SetEnvIf Referer "^https://example\.com" ref001
> SetEnvIf Referer "^$" ref001
> order deny,allow
> deny from all
> allow from env=ref001
> ```